# Await.result on HttpService

Tags: scala, future, slick-3.0, http4s, http4s-circe

I've a scala project with http4s 0.15.16a and slick 3.2.1 with these steps:

1. Receive a ID by rest call
2. passing ID to MySlickDAO  that responds with a Future
3. Call Await.result(res, Duration.Inf) on Future returned by MySlickDAO
4. Create the json

The problem is that I use a Await.result and this is bad practices
is there a better solution ?

Here the code:

```
  val service = HttpService {

//http://localhost:8080/rest/id/9008E75A-F112-396B-E050-A8C08D26075F
case GET -> Root / "rest" / "id" / id =>

  val res = MySlickDAO.load(id)

  Await.result(res, Duration.Inf)

  val ll = res.value.get.get
  ll match {
    case Failure(x) =>
      InternalServerError(x)
    case Success(record) =>
      val r = record.map(x => MyEntity(x._1, x._2, x._3))
      jsonOK(r.asJson)
  }
 case ....
```

}

Comment: Why making the `Future` blocking ?

Comment: @cchantep I wait for Future to finish

Comment: why? That's not the usual way of using `Future` (which is so losing all its interest)

Comment: jsonOK is a wrapper on OK:

def jsonOK(s1: Json): Task[Response] = Ok(removeNull(s1)).putHeaders(Header("Content-Type", "application/json"))

Comment: And so ? That's still blocking (there is also unsafe `.get`)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of awaiting, you can chain the result of one `Future` into another:

```
val resFut = MySlickDAO.load(id)
resFut.map { record =>
   val r = record.map(x => MyEntity(x._1, x._2, x._3))
   jsonOK(r.asJson)
} recover { x =>
   InternalServerError(x)
}
```

The result of this will be a `Future` of a common supertype of `jsonOK` and `InternalServerError` (not familiar with the libraries you're using; so I may have the type of load wrong: it's not a `Future[Try[_]]` is it?).

BTW: your original code has a very problematic line:

```
val ll = res.value.get.get
```

`res.value` is an `Option[Try[T]]`. Calling `get` on an `Option` or a `Try` is generally a bad idea (even though in this case because of the `Await`, the `Option` should never be `None`, so the `get` is technically safe) because it can throw an exception. You're much better off using `map`, `flatMap`, and friends.

Comment: map returns a Future and not a Task[Response] and so the problem remains

 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[scalaz.concurrent.Task[org.http4s.Response]]
 required: scalaz.concurrent.Task[org.http4s.Response]
      resFut.map { record =>

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that http4s 0.15 uses the Scalaz concurrency constructs, while Slick uses the native Scala ones, and the two aren't designed to work with each other. My understanding is that http4s 0.17+ has switched from Scalaz to Cats, which might entail using native Scala Futures, so if you can upgrade that might be worth a shot. If not, you can handle the conversion by manually creating a Task that wraps your future:

```
def scalaFutureRes = MySlickDAO.load(id)
val scalazTaskRes = Task.async { register =>
  scalaFutureRes.onComplete {
    case Success(success) => register(success.right)
    case Failure(ex)      => register(ex.left)
  }
}
```

At this point you've got a Task[ResultType] from the Future[ResultType] which you can map/flatMap with the rest of your logic like in Levi's answer.

You can also use the [delorean](https://github.com/Verizon/delorean) library for this which has this logic and the opposite direction defined on the classes in question via implicit conversions, so that you can just call .toTask on a Future to get it in a compatible form. Their readme also has a lot of useful information on the conversion and what pitfalls there are.